# linux tc + vlan interface

Tags: linux, vlan, tc

This is my tc simple script. It limit bandwidth based on source ip address and  use hashing filter based on /24 subnet. This example filter works but only when this example subnet 10.118.0.0/24 is add to physical interface eth1. When I switch this subnet to vlan interface for example eth1.100 traffic limiting stops working properly.

So this scenario work :

(PC 10.118.0.35 eth0) --- (SW) --- (eth1 ip 10.118.0.1 - NAT - eth0) --- INTERNET

But this don't:

(PC 10.118.0.35 eth0) --- (vlan 100 acces - SW - vlan 100 trunk) --- (eth1.100 ip 10.118.0.1 - NAT - eth0) --- INTERNET

```
#!/bin/bash
#UPLOAD
tc qdisc del root dev ifb1

tc qdisc add dev eth1 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth1 parent ffff: u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb1

tc qdisc add dev ifb1 root handle 1: prio bands 2 priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
tc qdisc add dev ifb1 parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq
tc filter add dev ifb1 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.90.0.0/16 flowid 1:1

tc qdisc add dev ifb1 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 htb

tc class add dev ifb1 parent 20:0 classid 20:1 htb rate 1024000kbit ceil 1024000kbit
tc class add dev ifb1 parent 20:1 classid 20:100 htb rate 51200kbit ceil 204800kbit

tc qdisc add dev ifb1 parent 20:100 sfq
tc class add dev ifb1 parent 20:1 classid 20:110 htb rate 972800kbit ceil 1013760kbit

tc filter add dev ifb1 parent 20:0 prio 1 handle 11: protocol ip u32 divisor 256
tc filter add dev ifb1 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 5 u32 ht 800:: match ip src 10.118.0.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 11:

tc class add dev ifb1 parent 20:110 classid 20:03E8 htb rate 1024kbit ceil 1024kbit
tc qdisc add dev ifb1 parent 20:03E8 handle 03E8 cake diffserv4 
tc filter add dev ifb1 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 200 u32 ht 11:23: match ip src 10.118.0.35 flowid 20:03E8

#DOWNLOAD
tc qdisc del root dev eth1

tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: prio bands 2 priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.90.0.0/16 flowid 1:1

#qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 hfsc default 100
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 htb

tc class add dev eth1 parent 20:0 classid 20:1 htb rate 1024000kbit ceil 1024000kbit
tc class add dev eth1 parent 20:1 classid 20:100 htb rate 51200kbit ceil 204800kbit

tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 20:100 sfq
tc class add dev eth1 parent 20:1 classid 20:110 htb rate 972800kbit ceil 1013760kbit

tc filter add dev eth1 parent 20:0 prio 1 handle 11: protocol ip u32 divisor 256
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 5 u32 ht 800:: match ip dst 10.118.0.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 16 link 11:

tc class add dev eth1 parent 20:110 classid 20:03E8 htb rate 1024kbit ceil 1024kbit
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 20:03E8 handle 03E8 cake diffserv4
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 200 u32 ht 11:23: match ip dst 10.118.0.35 flowid 20:03E8
```

Anyone know how this should look for vlan interface or is possible to run tc on vlan ?
During my search tc + vlan I was able only find tc filter based on vlan number but in this scenario this is not the case.

Comment: How did you test? Did you replace eth1 with eth1.100 in your script, or did you keep this script with eth1?

Comment: First I try to replace eth1 with eth1.100 but this don't work. Then I left eth1 but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else need this is solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
tc qdisc del root dev eth1.118

tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 root handle 1: prio bands 2 priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 parent 1:1 handle 10: cake diffserv4 #esfq hash src perturb 10
tc filter add dev eth1.118 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.90.0.0/16 flowid 1:1
tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 hfsc default 100
tc class add dev eth1.118 parent 20:0 classid 20:1 hfsc ls m2 1024000kbit ul m2 1024000kbit
tc class add dev eth1.118 parent 20:1 classid 20:100 hfsc ls m2 51200kbit ul m2 204800kbit
tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 parent 20:100 cake diffserv4 #esfq hash src perturb 5
tc class add dev eth1.118 parent 20:1 classid 20:110 hfsc ls m2 972800kbit ul m2 1013760kbit

tc filter add dev eth1.118 parent 20:0 prio 1 handle 11: protocol ip u32 divisor 256
tc filter add dev eth1.118 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 5 u32 ht 800:: match ip dst 10.118.0.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 16 link 11:

# ip=10.118.0.35 qdiscNo=1000 createQdisc=1 multiESFQ=0
tc class add dev eth1.118 parent 20:110 classid 20:03E8 hfsc ls m1 1024kbit d 2000ms m2 512kbit ul m1 2048kbit d 2000ms m2 1024kbit
tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 parent 20:03E8 handle 03E8 cake diffserv4 #sfq perturb 15
tc filter add dev eth1.118 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 200 u32 ht 11:23: match ip dst 10.118.0.35 flowid 20:03E8


tc qdisc del dev eth1.118 handle ffff: ingress
tc qdisc del root dev ifb0
tc qdisc add dev eth1.118 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth1.118 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0

tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: prio bands 2 priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 handle 10: cake diffserv4 #esfq hash src perturb 10
tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.90.0.0/16 flowid 1:1
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:2 handle 20:0 hfsc default 100
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 20:0 classid 20:1 hfsc ls m2 1024000kbit ul m2 1024000kbit
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 20:1 classid 20:100 hfsc ls m2 51200kbit ul m2 204800kbit
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 20:100 cake diffserv4 #esfq hash src perturb 5
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 20:1 classid 20:110 hfsc ls m2 972800kbit ul m2 1013760kbit

tc filter add dev ifb0 parent 20:0 prio 1 handle 11: protocol ip u32 divisor 256
tc filter add dev ifb0 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 5 u32 ht 800:: match ip src 10.118.0.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 11:

# ip=10.118.0.35 qdiscNo=1000 createQdisc=1 multiESFQ=0
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 20:110 classid 20:03E8 hfsc ls m1 1024kbit d 2000ms m2 512kbit ul m1 2048kbit d 2000ms m2 1024kbit
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 20:03E8 handle 03E8 cake diffserv4 #sfq perturb 15
tc filter add dev ifb0 protocol ip parent 20:0 prio 200 u32 ht 11:23: match ip src 10.118.0.35 flowid 20:03E8
```

The key is "hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 16" in one interface and "hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12" on second one.
I don't know why this working but it works.
Can someone explain why this option must be set on 12 and 16 ?